# Get component dimensions before paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing

I'm painting my own component that extends JPanel:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

This works nicely.

I need to do quite a bit of work the prepare the component. This work depends on the dimensions of the component.

The dimensions of the component only seem to be available in the `paintComponent()` function. So I now do:

```
if(firstTime){
//do init
firstTime=false
}
//draw
```

In my `paintComponent()` function. I'm not in love with this solution.

Is there a way that I can get the dimensions before the `paintComponent()` function is called?
(it doesn't seem to be valid in the constructor)

Comment: May be use `ComponentListener` and its `componentShown`?

Comment: Ok, I'll make an answer.

Comment: @cybersoft Gave it a quick test, but paintComponent is called before componentResized . Strangely componentShown is never called of my ComponentAdapter, taking a better peek.

Comment: @TinusSky, yes, you are right.

Comment: You can always get the dimensions inside of paintComponent, and sometimes this is a good idea, since they can potentially change. You can also get the `preferredSize` of the component at any time. What are you using the information for specifically?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm a bit afraid that paintComponent is called multiple times resulting in my init code executed twice (even with a simple firstTime flag). I'm using the information to eval a script using the nashorn javascript engine, the executed script needs the dimension.

Comment: Why would the script be called from within paintComponent? Please give more background information if you can.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the script also does a bit of painting, so it needs the dimensions. It is quite experimental ;-) So before it can do it's painting the script does need to initialize, and that takes a bit of time.

Comment: I can say this: `paintComponent(...)` should involve itself with painting and painting only, and probably should not be calling scripts or such. Perhaps what you want to do is call your script from some other event, such as from a Swing Timer or a PropertyChangeListener, set data in your program, call `repaint()` and then use the data to paint with. Or paint to a BufferedImage with the data and call `repaint()`. I doubt though that calling `getSize()` is going to provide much of a bottleneck here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The problem was that my init method called from paintComponent could be called multiple times when paintComponent is called multiple times at the virtually the same time (even with the firstTime boolean, shouldn't happen but happens rarely). In addition init an entire engine in a paint function didn't make much sense. I think i now solved it by using a Object lock and creating a synchronized block locking the lock object in my paintComponent function. It still stops the painting of the component. Wish there was a cleaner way though.

Comment: That sounds dangerous to me as that can only slow down painting, something that should never be done. I have a sneaking suspicion that you might want to use a SwingWorker to do background calculations and even create images, and then publish the data to the GUI for display.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, i agree, i will experiment a bit with moving it to a thread and signalling the component when it is ready. Although it does complicate things with those difficult concurrency issues. Cheers for the ideas!

Comment: Sounds like Proxy design pattern is useful here...

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to draw to a `BufferedImage` instead.  Obviously (or at least, I **hope** it is obvious) we give the image a size when creating it.

We get a `Graphics2D` obect like this:

```
Graphics2D g = bi.creatGraphics();
```

The image can be displayed in a `JLabel`:

```
JLabel label == new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));  // now add the label to something..
```

To refresh the label after new painting call:

```
label.repaint();
```

---

But like @HovercraftFullOfEels I have doubts that this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems such code would work as expecting:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addHierarchyListener((event) -> {
    if((event.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0) {
        // before paintComponent
    }
});
```

Comment: componentShown never seem to be called. While research this i found the following interesting discussion on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5777914/2384902 "Do not use ComponentListener for notification of "showing". That's left-over from AWT-age.
Do use AncestorListener. That seems to be the Swing replacement, slightly misnomed notification of "added" which actually means "showing"
Do use HierarchyListener only if really interested in fine-grained state changes "

Comment: Hmm, I've tested recently and came to the same conclusion... thanks for replacement, didn't know:)

Comment: `AncestorListener.ancestorMoved()` seems to be the solution! `HierarchyListener` did nothing for me, the event wasn't even called once in the startup sequence of my program. Side note, it's bad practice to abuse a one-method interface like `HierarchyListener` or `ActionListener` as a lambda, when they're not made for it.

Comment: @TinusSky I like to thank you and criticize you at the same time. `AncestorListener` worked great, but how is `ComponentListener` an AWT-left-over? What other way is there to listen to component size changes? (hint: not `HierarchyListener`)